# Java: How to Count a Character in a String

Tags: java

I have to count the number of times that a character appears in a string.

I know this question has been asked previously.  However, the solutions that I've seen use commands/techniques that I haven't yet covered in class.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/*
This program counts the number of occourances of a char in a string.
*/

public class LetterCounter
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
int i, length, count=0;
String input;
char letter1, letter2;

// Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

// Get a string from user
System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
input = stdin.nextLine();

// Get a character from user 
System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
letter1 = stdin.next().charAt(0);

//Determine the length of the string
length = input.length();

//Count the number of times the user selected character appears in the string
for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) 
{
    letter2 = input.charAt(i);
    if (letter1 == letter2)
{
count++;
}
}

System.out.printf("Occurrences of a %s in %s is %d", letter1, input, count);
```

}
}

Here is the output from jgrasp:

----jGRASP exec: java LetterCounter
Enter a string: hello world
Enter a character: l
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at LetterCounter.main(LetterCounter.java:37)

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

I don't understand the errors.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `i < length` instead of `i <= length`.

Comment: That exception is pretty clear. What would you think *string index out of bounds* might mean, especially when it's followed by *string index out of range: 11* with a reference to `String.charAt()`? Where do you see `String.charAt()` in the code you've posted? What might cause that to throw an exception about a *string index out of range*?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're just iterating for too long:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

I noticed that you wrote this line of code:

```
if (letter1 == letter2)
{
    count++
}
```

I'd avoid using count++, you may end up getting mixed with ++count sometime. Sticking with the following is always good

```
if (letter1 == letter2) {
    count + =1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is occurring in the below line of code -

```
for (i = 0; i <= length; i++)
```

Here Iteration is longer than input length [exceeds the range].
The revised code will be -

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

Need anything more? Shoot me a comment please.

Hopefully, it will work fine.